# How to get input text on focused using javascript & tagName (no jQuery) without calling onfocus() method

Tags: javascript, input

I would like to get input field value on focused using pure javascript(no jquery). Also it should be automatic hence we should not call onfocus() function on input element.

I used this below syntax to get the input field. But how to make this automatic on focused.

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(i=0; i<el.length; i++){
      console.log(el[i].value);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to add "the below syntax" and what exactly do you want? You want the input fields value stored onto a variable on focus? Or you you want to focus the input field element once the site loads?

Comment: @noa-dev-59: I have added now. How to get a value of input element when it it focused without adding onfocus() in input element. I would like to get the value once the site is loaded.

Comment: it's not clear what would you like to achieve. Would you like to display the value? There is no magic here, no way not to use some sort of function

Comment: add `input eventlistener`, [check](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_oninput.asp)

Comment: @Durga 2: addEventListener may work. But how to add to input fields.

Comment: [check this](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get the value of your input field without the onfocus() method, but with the native javaScript one.

```
input.addEventListener("focus", function(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

or using your array of input fields:

```
for(i=0; i<el.length; i++){
  el[i].addEventListener("focus", function(e){console.log(e.target.value)})
}
```

And heres a fiddle of a working example.. https://jsfiddle.net/wdur4yvb/

** edit **

you could also add the event of "click" instead of focus since once you click the input it will be focused as well... no idea what sort of solution you are looking for and why, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is what i was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`autofocus` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

Comment: Can u write a sample code that will get the value of input element when it is focused using javascript.

Comment: `we should not call onfocus()`, `can you write code for me`..... Smells like homework, so, yeah, no